# filepaths and files in Python

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

I have code that works until I try to get it to read the information from a file instead of a list I define. No error message currently but it just prints `{}`

I'm having a hard time understanding what's going wrong. I read about working with files and watched some YouTube videos but it's not clear to me.

Here's my current code:

```
file_path = ('C:/myfolder/text.txt')

my_dict = {}
Alphabet = ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z")
def letter_count(my_dict):
    with open(file_path,'r',encoding='utf-8') as file:
        data = infile.read()
        for line in file:
            for letter in line:
                if letter in Alphabet:   
                    if letter.isalpha():
                        if letter in my_dict.keys():
                            my_dict[letter]+= 1
                        else:
                            my_dict[letter] =1
print(my_dict)
```

What the code is supposed to do is read from a file, count letters a-z, if it's A-Z convert to a-z. Then count the number of times each letter occurs in a dictionary.

Comment: You never call the letter_count function

Comment: You saved my bacon, thank you!